# Copy a list of managed strings to an array of wchar_t in C++/CLI

Tags: string, c++-cli

What is the easiest way to copy a list of managed strings, `List<String^>^` to an array of `wchar_t`s?

So from `List<String^>^ someList`
I need to copy it to a new array, say:

```
wchar_t *paramList = new wchar_t[sizeoflist];
```

And while we are on this topic, can someone point to a good C++/CLI reference (book/online article) that explains these aspects?

Comment: One at a time.  There are a *lot* of questions about one string already.  Just look at the Related column on the right of this page.

Comment: Are you sure you need _TCHAR?

Comment: @TomBlodget: wchar_t will do. I have updated the question.

Comment: You mean copy multiple `String`s into a single `wchar_t` array? How do you want to seperate the individual strings in this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than ask questions about questions (see question comments from @HanPassant and @ChristianRau), here is a spike to get you thinking about what you really want:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace System;
using namespace std;

// preserves UTF-16LE encoding
vector<wstring> StringArrayToNative(array<String ^>^ arr)
{
    vector<wstring> v;
    v.reserve(arr->Length);
    for each (String^ s in arr)
    {
        // copies from the CLR GC heap to the C++ heap.
        v.push_back(msclr::interop::marshal_as<wstring>(s));
    }
    return v;
}
```

`wstring` is, of course, comprised of `wchart_t` elements. `wchar_t` was intended for portable code and was supposed to hold a native-sized character. It's being supplanted by standard-sized types since, after all, character encodings are standards. Unfortunately, `char16_t` is not built into the C++/CLI toolset. Nonetheless, in all of MSVC, `wchar_t` has a size of 2 bytes and on Windows is typically used to hold exactly one UTF-16LE code unit of the Unicode character set. That makes it the thing to use for Win32 APIs. (BTW—Microsoft calls UTF-16LE, simply "Unicode".)

Comment: worked for me, just could impove by checking if s is not nullptr